# Allowing user to specify account type, business or personal

Tags: usability, website-design

In our company, most users have personal accounts, but some are used for business.

Traditionally, they were all treated the same, and we don't have a lot of visibility into which is which.

We'd like to change that and have business owners explicitly tell us they are operating as a business and allow them to supply some additional information (company name, etc.).

Here's the current mock-up we're working with. The idea is to default the account to "personal" since that's the majority of users, but allow them to switch it. The ? would bring up a dialog explaining the difference.

Questions: 1. Is this clear? 2. Is there a better way to handle it or a better convention to use?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is clear regarding UX, although if your users do not know why this change is important, **I would add a little "why"**.

However, as some Users may skip the selection of the profile type (Personal or Business), to improve results **I would not make any of the profile types preselected**.

Instead, I would **first ask them what type of profile** they want to create, and only **after that display the set of fields** required to create such profile.

Comment: Thanks, Dominik. To clarify, this is the page that *any* user sees when they go to edit their profile. We have 2M+ users already, without any personal/business classification. We could force them to select the account type first when they go to edit, but since 90%+ are personal, we thought we'd default to personal.

Comment: I think for existing accounts it may be easy if you ask your Users "Are you using this account for personal or business purposes?" Just after they log in. I believe that (unless there is anything that would make this answer hard to give) most of the Users would only see it once.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple check box labeled BUSINESS, with perhaps a question mark icon to explain the difference. Of course the checkbox will be unselected by default.

Or You could have boxes to select

```
Personal                      Business
descriptive text              descriptive text
```

Have a colored border around the personal box, with a light grey border around the business box, to indicate which one is selected.

I would not however make a previous step to choose business or personal before they get to the form, it will likely hurt conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you could consider is having a checkbox option in the case that they want to create a business account. I used this way of representing it because most of your users make private accounts.

After the user clicks the checkbox, you could present the fields, like "company name" etc.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhJoXd.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>